# Continually request image until found

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, interface, upload

I am working on an interface that allows for an image to be uploaded asynchronously, and the process is working as expected. The process submits the image to a backend process that manages resizing the image to different sized and stores them on the cloud. i generate the url, and eventually the image is uploaded (usually in less than 10 seconds) to the appropriate resize.

After the image is uploaded, there's no thumbnail displayed for that image in the interface, obviously, because it hasn't been resized yet.

What I'd like to do, is, after creation of the image, and submission to the backend service for resize, a process on the client attached to each upload attempt (which I am thinking of using a setinterval for) to keep looking for that image until it resolves, and once it does resolve, update the thumbnail placeholder with that image.

Once the image does resolve by request, how do I feed that to update the interface?

Comment: A simple solution might be to use "setTimeout" to checked every x seconds for the image until it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you determine there is no image there (404 error, some sort of API returning JSON with a URL?), you could use jQuery.ajax() to quite easily act based on the HTTP status code.

```
function waitforimage(imageURL) {
    $.ajax(url, { 
        statusCode: {
            // on 404 wait and do it again later
            404: function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    waitforimage(imageURL);
                }, 3000);
            },
            // on success, load the image
            200: function() {
                loadimage(imageURL);
            }
        }
    });
}

function loadimage(imageURL) {
     $('#myimageID').attr('src', imageURL);
}
```

Of course, you can do it without jQuery, but there'll be more fiddling around to get it working.

Comment: Shouldn't success be `200`?

Answer (score 0):

[Pure JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/kTr77/) using the `setTimeout`, `onerror` and `onload` events:

```
var img,
    attempt = 2;

checkForImage("https://ssl.gstatic.com/apps/cpanel/resources/img/apps_logo_new.png3",
             document.getElementById("message"));

function checkForImage(location, loadto) {    
    img = document.createElement("img")

    img.onerror = function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            checkForImage(location, loadto);
            loadto.innerText = "Finding Picture... Attempt: " + attempt++;
        }, 5000); 
    }

    img.src = location;

    img.onload = function () {
        loadto.innerHTML = "<img src='" + location + "' />";
    }
}
```

Removing the `3` at the end of the `image` link will show a successful example.